# Comparing columns of different dataframes conditionally in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes, each has the same columns 1) the response made by a participant 2) the response time in seconds and milliseconds (s.ms). 
For example,

```
subjectData = 

Key     RT
0   v   2.20
1   v   4.34
2   v   5.51
3   v  10.39
4   w  12.50
5   v  14.62
6   v  20.22
```

I also have a dataframe that is the 'correct' responses and times. For example,

```
correctData = 

Key     RT
0   v   2.25
1   w   4.34
2   v   5.61
3   v  20.30
```

I want to indicate that there is a match in both response key AND the response time within -+1 second. So, first check that the response key matches, and if it does, then compare the time that this response occurred. If it occurred within 1s, it is deemed correct. 
Notice that the subject may have responded more times than was correct. So I want to compare these columns regardless of order. For example, notice above that the 6th response in the subjectData frame matches the 3rd in the correctData frame (within one second). Because of this, the third entry in the output is TRUE, indicating that the third correct answer was matched.

So the end result should look like this

```
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
```

Notice that the output is the same length as the correctData dataframe, and indicates which correct answers match the subjectData. 
So it indicates that the subject got it correctly IF they pressed the correct button, within one second of the 'correct' time listed in the dataframe provided. Please note that these dataframes will most likely NOT be the same length (the subject may respond more or less than the 'correct' number of responses). So 'join' may not work here.

Any ideas on how to do this most efficiently?

Comment: If the dataframes are different lengths, should the resulting boolean list be the same length as the subjectData or the correctData?

Comment: the resulting boolean should be the length of the correctData if possible....thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subjectData = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'w', 'v', 'v'],
                            'RT': [2.20, 4.34, 5.51, 10.39, 12.50, 14.62, 20.22]})

correctData = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['v', 'w', 'v', 'v'],
                            'RT': [2.25, 4.34, 5.61, 20.30]})

df = subjectData.merge(correctData.reset_index(), on='Key', how='right', 
                       suffixes=['_subj', '_corr'])

df_timed = df[(df['RT_subj'] - df['RT_corr']).between(-1,1)]

correctData.index.isin(df_timed['index'])
```

Output:

```
array([ True, False,  True,  True])
```

Comment: HI and thank you for your answer! I get an error that says, " ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Comment: @Katie Oh sorry, earlier I missed the requirement for dataframes of different lengths. I've edited my answer to support that as well.

Comment: @EliadL...I thought this worked, but upon closer inspection, it's not quite right. I am hoping to compare the columns regardless of time order. That is, it may be that the 3 response in the correctData dataframe matches the 6 response in the subjectData dataframe. Is there a way to ensure that regardless of row I am getting those that match? Thank you!

Comment: @Katie please edit your question to include and demonstrate this new criterion.

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully this is more clear. Thank you!

Comment: @Katie I've edited the answer accordingly. Please consider accepting it if  satisfies your criteria.

Comment: this is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Use [DataFrame.eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) 
to compare the `key` column of both dataframe:

```
cond1=subjectData['Key'].eq(correctData['Key'])
```

**2)** then check if it is in the range of `+ -1s`

```
cond2=(subjectData['RT']<(correctData['RT']+1))&(subjectData['RT']>(correctData['RT']-1))
```

**3)** finally check which rows meet both conditions (`con1,cond2`):

```
cond1&cond2

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help! I got an error stating that, " ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `numpy.isclose`

```
(subjectData.Key == correctData.Key) & np.isclose(subjectData.RT, correctData.RT, atol=1)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Key, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
cutoff_at_index = min(correctData.shape[0], subjectData.shape[0])
equal = subjectData.Key[:cutoff_at_index] == correctData.Key[:cutoff_at_index]
between = (subjectData.RT[:cutoff_at_index] >= correctData.RT[:cutoff_at_index]-1) \
          & (subjectData.RT[:cutoff_at_index] <=correctData.RT[:cutoff_at_index]+1)
equal & between
```

Comment: HI and thank you for your answer! I get an error that says, " ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"